# How to make a cigarette air filter?

Tags: air-filter

I live with smokers and want to make a air filter to catch the particle left in the air. I learned one good way to do this is with heavy wet cloth. But how can I turn this whole idea into a filter to protect me I need thing that can protect within a good distance maybe 10 ft or so. Any ideas?

Comment: Stop living with people that smoke!! Move to another location.

Comment: Before or after the junk is cycled through your lungs? If this was remotely feasible the concerns about second-hand smoke would be moot.

Answer (score 2):

The only good way to protect yourself is to not be around them.

They should smoke outside or you will need a high quality respirator.

Good luck!

Comment: Am now picturing someone casually sitting on the couch wearing a full biohazard suit with their roommates smoking around them.

Answer (score 1):

most of the nasties in residual smoke are chemical in nature and not particulate.  you wont be able to catch those with a mechanical filter like you want.  time to start looking for a new home or convince them to smoke outside.